# Competetive coding algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This is a problem from an ongoing competition.
https://www.codechef.com/AUG17/problems/CHEFFA

Given an array `A = (A1, A2, ..., AN)`, which has **N integers** in it initially. Now for `i ≥ 1, if Ai > 0, Ai+1 > 0`, and `Ai+2` exists, then he can decrease both `Ai`, and `Ai+1` by one and increase `Ai+2` by one. If `Ai+2` doesn't exist, but `Ai > 0`, and `Ai+1 > 0`, then he can decrease both `Ai`, and `Ai+1` (which will be the currently last two elements of the array) by one and add a new element at the end, whose value is 1.

Calculate the number of different arrays that are possible to make from A using this operation as many times.

Suppose array is {2,3,1}: then: All possible arrays are :

```
(2, 3, 1) → (2, 2, 0, 1)

(2, 2, 0, 1) → (1, 1, 1, 1)

(1, 1, 1, 1) → (1, 1, 0, 0, 1)

(1, 1, 0, 0, 1) → (0, 0, 1, 0, 1)

(1, 1, 1, 1) → (1, 0, 0, 2)

(1, 1, 1, 1) → (0, 0, 2, 1)

(2, 3, 1) → (1, 2, 2)

(1, 2, 2) → (0, 1, 3)
```

So the answer is 9.

Note:

I know that this can be done using dynamic programming but don't have any idea how, I tried doing using recursion but getting TLE. I don't expect the full solution but a little bit of direction is all I need.

Comment: This is a current [CodeChef challenge](https://www.codechef.com/AUG17/problems/CHEFFA).  Posting here for help violates the contest [code of conduct](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/18662/does-codechef-have-any-code-of-conduct)

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @keyvanvafaee: regarding your edit here, again there are more quote devices for material that is not a quote. Please do not add these merely as decoration.

Comment: Ok , i note that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following **pseudocode**:

```
result = 1
queue = {array}
while queue is not empty
    array = queue.pop()
    n = array.length()
    for i from 0 to n-2
        if array[i] * array[i+1] >0
            temp = array
            temp[i] -= 1 
            temp[i+1] -= 1
            temp[i+2] += 1
            if temp not already present in queue
                queue.push(temp)
                result += 1
    if array[n-1] * array[n-2] >0
        array[n-1] -= 1 
        array[n-2] -= 1
        array.push(1)
        if array not already present in queue
                queue.push(array)
                result += 1
print result
```

The value result will be the number of possible arrays.
Algorithm may be inefficient for large size of array or large array values.

Comment: I tried that using listoflists but was getting TLE ,I am pretty sure that it can be done using dynamic programming